# What plant/weed is this?

Tags: trees, weeds

quick question, does anyone know what plant this is? Each branch has 5 leaves. My wife and I are not sure if it’s a weed.

Many thanks!
Ray[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're in North America or Europe, that's a member of the Aesculus genus, which includes horse chestnut and buckeye. Many of these trees look very similar, but if I had to bet on it, I'd bet that it's a horse chestnut (*Aesculus hippocastanum*).